# use indirect relation when intermediate model is empty

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8, eloquent-relationship

i have made indirect relation from one model to another in couple of my models.

this is my `Work` Model:

```
public function GeoEntities()
{
    return $this->hasMany(\App\GeoEntity::class);
}

public function geoLand()
{
    $builder = $this->GeoEntities()->where("entity_type", 0);
    $relation = new HasOne($builder->getQuery(), $this, 'work_id', 'id');
    return $relation;
}

public function geoLandPoints()
{
    return $this->geoLand->geoPoints();
}
```

this `return $this->intermediateModel->FinalModel();` would work, if **intermediate relation** is **belongsTo()** and returns a relation instance.

but in this case, when `geoLand` is **Empty** it produce error:

> Call to a member function geoPoints() on null

like below line:

```
$points = $work->geoLandPoints;
```

- The Intermediate Relation is a **hasMany**

i want to have this like relation call `geoLandPoints` and not `geoLandPoints()` but,

when **intermidate models** are null, i want an **empty** relation.

but i can not figure it out, how to achieve this.

### with Fico7489\Laravel\EloquentJoin\Traits\EloquentJoin

using `Fico7489\Laravel\EloquentJoin\Traits\EloquentJoin` package, i have tried to refactor relation like below:

```
public function geoLandPoints()
{
    $builder = $this
        ->select("works.*")
        ->join("geo_entities", "works.id", "geo_entities.work_id")
        ->join("geo_points", "geo_entities.id", "geo_points.geo_entity_id")
        ->where("entity_type", 0)
        ->where("works.id", $this->id);
    return new HasMany($builder->getQuery(), $this, "work_id", "id");
}
```

but it couldn't convert **Database Query Builder** to **Eloquent Query Builder**.

> Argument 1 passed to
> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany::__construct()
> must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder, instance
> of Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use the `hasOne()` method instead of trying to return your own `HasOne` class? Also, you can use `withDefault()` so the relationship returns an empty `GeoEntity` instead of `null`.

```
public function geoLand()
{
    return $this->hasOne(\App\GeoEntity::class)->where("entity_type", 0)->withDefault();
}
```

You could even pass an array of default values. `withDefault(['column' => 'value', 'column2' => 'value2', ...])`

Comment: it is a good technique to use **withDefault** and using **hasOne** in this situation. thanks